# Range queries on a large collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have document collection with around 40 million documents(~10GB). The documents in this collection are fairly small(~1000 bytes). The main fields of interest are as follows:

```
start_x     integer
end_x       integer
```

I have a query to return a row for a given value of x. For a value of x there can ever be only one matching row in the collection. I am using following selector for this purpose:

```
"start_x"=>{"$lte"=>1258}, "end_x"=>{"$gte"=> 1258}
```

I am not getting the expected performance for the query. I started with a compound index (start_x =1 , end_x = 1). The query plan showed around 400K nscanned

```
{
  "cursor"=>"BtreeCursor start_x_1_end_x_1", 
  "nscanned"=>417801, 
  "nscannedObjects"=>1, 
  "n"=>1, 
  "millis"=>3548, 
  "nYields"=>0, 
  "nChunkSkips"=>0, 
  "isMultiKey"=>false,
  "indexOnly"=>false
}
```

Subsequently, I added stand-alone index on start_x and end_x fields. The query plan didn't show much improvement.

- Why is `indexOnly` not true even though I have a compound index and all the fields used in the query are covered by the index?
- Is there a way to optimize this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using indexed lookup on the `end_x` field to address this issue.

- Dropped all the indexes on the collection
- Added a ASC index on `end_x` field.
- Queried the first matching row with top bound equal or above the given value

  ```
  row = Model.where(:end_x.gte => 1258).asc(:end_x).limit(1).first
  ```
- Checked to ensure the row returned is indeed the matching range

  ```
  row = (row.present? and 1258.between?(row.start_x, row.end_x)) ? row : nil
  ```